# Question from Chapter 1 of Cornell, Silverman, Stevens "Modular Forms and Fermat's Last Theorem."

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, modular-forms

On page 14 of the text, Stevens seems to imply that Lemma 7.8 is immediate from the result of Serre in the previous paragraph. However, I do not see why the residual mod $p$ representation attached to our elliptic curve $E$, denoted $\overline{\rho}_{E,p}$, must satisfy Stevens' Condition D (see page 12) that its restriction to $G(\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-3}))$ is absolutely irreducible. The result of Serre that the author quotes only applies when $p = 3$ by the author's own admission, but Lemma 7.8 merely requires that we deal with a prime $p$ *at least* 3. So what if $p$ is a prime larger than 3? How do we get Condition D?

Comment: I think condition D should depend on $p$ - i.e. the condition should be that the restriction to $G(\mathbb Q(\sqrt{p^*}))$ is irreducible (where $p^* = (-1)^{(p-1)/4}p$). But, in any case, if $\overline\rho$ becomes reducible on restriction to any quadratic extension, then it cannot be surjective, so that statement does not require $p = 3$.

Comment: So what you're saying is that the irreducibility of the residual rep implies its irreducibility when restricted to a quadratic extension? I thought the converse was instead true.

Comment: No that's not true. But Serre's result is that $\overline\rho_{E, p}$ is either reducible or surjective.

Comment: So, then, I'm sorry, but I don't see exactly how your reply answers my question. It also seems that my comment is correct based on serre's result if your comment is correct. You said if we restrict to the quadratic extension and are reducible, the original guy isn't surjective. By Serre, it must be irreducible. Taking the contrapositive gives my comment which you said was incorrect (unless you meant that the converse was incorrect).

Comment: Serre's result is that if $E$ is a semisistable elliptic curve and if $p\ge 3$, then $\overline\rho_{E, p}$ is either reducible or surjective. If $\overline\rho_{E, p}|_{K}$ is reducible for any quadratic extension $K$ then $\overline\rho_{E, p}$ is not surjective. Hence it is reducible. Taking the contrapositive, we see that that if $\overline\rho_{E, p}$ is irreducible, so is its restriction to $K$

Comment: My point is that the converse is what is true in general. But in this special case, because of Serre's result, both directions hold.

Comment: Excellent. How do we bump up to absolute irreducibility?

Comment: Also, how do I see that $\overline{\rho}_{E,p}$ is not surjective if it restricts to a reducible rep?

Comment: Surjective implies absolute irreducibility: $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb F_p)\hookrightarrow\mathrm{GL}_2(\overline{\mathbb F_p})$ is an irreducible representation. For your second question, if $\overline\rho$ restricts to a reducible rep, then it has an index two subgroup that is contained in a Borel. So it can't be surjective.

Comment: One thing: why contained in a Borel?

Comment: A Borel subgroup in $\mathrm{GL}_2$ is just a subgroup that has a stable line. That stable line gives you your subrepresentation

Comment: Would you mind explaining precisely why the fact that the fact that the image has an index 2 subgroup in a Borel means the rep cannot be surjective?

Comment: There are lots of ways, but the simplest is just counting. A Borel subgroup is much smaller than $|\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb F_p)|/2$.